# How to create complex list in android?

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, adapter

I want to create a complex recycler view with different rows.

How it is possible?

Like this picture:
[Three types of list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/em0Pv.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display severel types of listview row layout in your RecyclerView - you dont need multiple adapters

You need to override the getItemCount and the getItemViewType methods of the recycler view and tell it how much types you want to display in the list look at this: [RecyclerView item count](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html)

Here is an example:

the adapter:

```
public class NotificationsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MultipleRowViewHolder> {

private LayoutInflater inflater = null;

// notification list
private List<Notification> notificationList;

public NotificationsAdapter(Context context, List<Notification> multipleRowModelList){
    this.notificationList = multipleRowModelList;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public MultipleRowViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = null;

    if (viewType == NotificationType.Lick.getValue())
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lick_row_item, parent, false);
    else if (viewType == NotificationType.Comment.getValue())
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.comment_list_row, parent, false);
    else if (viewType == NotificationType.ViewMyProfile.getValue())
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_my_profile_list_row, parent, false);
    else // if notification is not of the first three types get the view_my_profile_list_row layout
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_my_profile_list_row, parent, false);

    return new MultipleRowViewHolder(view, viewType);
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MultipleRowViewHolder holder, int position) {

    try {
        // display enum type as title
        holder.titleTV.setText(NotificationType.toNotificationType(Integer.valueOf(notificationList.get(position).getType())).name());
        // display pretty date
        holder.actionTimeTV.setText(TimeUtils.getPrettyTimeDifference(notificationList.get(position).getActionTime()));
        holder.sourceUserNameTV.setText(notificationList.get(position).getSourceUserName());
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e(NotificationReader.TAG,e.getMessage());
    }
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return notificationList.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    Notification multipleRowModel = notificationList.get(position);

    if (multipleRowModel != null)
        return Integer.valueOf(multipleRowModel.getType());

    return super.getItemViewType(position);
}
```

The data model:

```
public class MultipleRowViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

public TextView titleTV;
public TextView sourceUserNameTV;
public TextView actionTimeTV;

private int type;

public MultipleRowViewHolder(View itemView, int type) {
    super(itemView);

    titleTV = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleTV);
    sourceUserNameTV = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.sourceUserNameTV);
    actionTimeTV = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.actionTimeTV);

    this.type = type;

}
```

}

Comment: so I have to create a struct with all the elements of two lists ? right ?

Comment: Yes, in the adapter you need to have both types of elements stored in a list of your choosing and in the onBindViewHolder according to the object type fill its layout attributes

Comment: Thanks a lot, you save me

Answer (score 0):

So, you need to have two different types of items in your list? Use RecyclerView instead of ListView, because it already implement ViewHolderPattern. In adapter, there is method .onBindViwHolder(), receiving int variable, rescribing element type. use it for binding your view

Comment: I use RecyclerView but I didn't know how can I send two type of struct to its adapter

Comment: create base class and extent it for each of your struct. Pass reference to base class to your adapter.

Answer (score 0):

it can also be done in listview, all you need to do is inflate view in `getView()` method of baseadapter according to condition

For eg:

```
public void getView()
{
  if(some condition)
{
view=LayoutInflator.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout1,parent,null);

//bind the related elements in the view accordingly;
}
else
{

view=LayoutInflator.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout2,parent,null);

//bind the related elements in the view accordingly;
}
}
```